# how i can make compare of multiple columns based on specific column on the table?

Tags: r, dplyr

i have a table and i want to compare multiple columns based on specific column on the table

for example :

my table names is x2 and has four columns which they ( A  , B , C , speed )

```
A  B  C  speed 
5  4  5    5
2  4  2    2
6  2  7    2
```

I want to compare columns A and B and C based on column speed

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, in case we want to check whether columns are equal to the `speed` one:

```r
outer(list(df$speed), list(df$A, df$B, df$C), Vectorize(\(x,y) all(x == y)))

#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: The result is boolean I want the result to be a numbercal to draw to compare these three columns

Comment: That is not clear what you mean. Could you please elaborate upon it, @ِAseelMohammed?

Comment: okay one minute

Comment: mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg ,disp,hp ) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), list(sum))) %>% 
  gather(activities, value) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = value / sum(value),
         label = percent(ratio %>% round(4))) %>% 
  mutate(activities = factor(activities, 
                             labels = c('A','B', 'C'))) %>%

Comment: ggplot(aes(x = (activities), 
             y = value, 
             label = label, 
             fill = activities)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_label(aes(label = label), 
             fill = "beige", 
             colour = "black",
             vjust = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Accent") +
  theme(legend.position="none")

Comment: as you can see the plot show the three different of three column but based on value , i want to compare it based  on the carb column  ?

Comment: for example :
i have three columns which is mpg and disp and hp in mtcars column and i want make compare those columns based on carb column

Comment: For instance, to make things clear, what should the result of the comparison between `speed` and `A` be, @ِAseelMohammed?

Comment: in the three columns have different values which when we compare it its give the highest based on sum total number , but here i dont want to compare it baesed on the value i want to compre it based on 
 specific column " speed "

Comment: Could you please be more specific, @ِAseelMohammed? Taking your example dataset, what should the result of the comparison between `A` and `speed`, `B` and `speed` and `C` and `speed` be?

Comment: thank you for your interest , i will explain more

Comment: A <- c(5, 7, 13, 15, 19)
speed <- c(23, 41, 50, 60, 70)
df <- data.frame(A, speed )
ggplot(df)+geom_line(aes(A,speed))

Comment: in the above example i have correlation between column A and speed , but what if i have another column like B and C and i want to make compare between them based on speed at the same graph ?

Comment: Maybe the following? `ggplot(df, aes(date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = speed, y = A, colour = "A")) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = speed, y = B, colour = "B")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = speed, y = C, colour = "C"))`